# jQuery UI sortable cancel option for multiple nested levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I would like to connect multiple nested sortables and define that only elements with a certain css class are actually sortable while all other elements still provide to be sortable targets without being sortable by themselfs.
As far as I know I can accomplish that with the `cancel` option but I don't find a way to specify a selector that is valid on all nested levels as I don't know the amount of levels at this point.
In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdun28bj/19/) it works on the second level but not on the others. In the first level for example the disabled elements are still sortable and on the third level nothing is sortable at all.

Any hints that help to do that are much appreciated (and upvoted)!

Thanks,

Sandro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be over complicating this. I don't think you actually need to know how many levels there are. Try just adding a class to the "disabled" elements. Then you can make everything sortable like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
                    connectWith: ".sortable",
                    cancel: ".notsortable"
    });
});
```

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdun28bj/20/), and included the full code here:

```js
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable",
        cancel: ".notsortable"
    });
});
```

```css
.sortable {
    padding-left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="sortable">
<div class="notsortable">Item 1 (disabled)</div>
<div>Item 2</div>
<div>Item 3</div>
<div class="notsortable">Item 4 (disabled)</div>
<div class="notsortable">Item 5 (disabled)</div>
<div>Item 6
    <div class="sortable">
        <div class="notsortable">Item 6.1 (disabled)</div>
        <div class="notsortable">Item 6.2 (disabled)</div>
        <div>Item 6.3</div>
        <div>Item 6.4</div>
        <div>Item 6.5</div>
        <div class="sortable">
            <div>Item 6.5.1</div>
            <div>Item 6.5.2</div>
            <div>Item 6.5.3</div>
            <div class="notsortable">Item 6.5.4 (disabled)</div>
            <div class="notsortable">Item 6.5.5 (disabled)</div>
            <div class="sortable">
                <div class="notsortable">Item 6.5.5.1 (disabled)</div>
                <div class="notsortable">Item 6.5.5.2 (disabled)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>Item 7</div>
</div>
```

**Update:** Since you cannot add a class to the "disabled" elements, try this:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
                    connectWith: ".sortable",
                    cancel: "div:not(.enabled,.sortable)"
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vdun28bj/22/). I colored all "disabled" elements red as well with the same selector just for illustration.

Comment: It's good to know that it works like this.
But in my case I only have influence on the sortable items and not on the others. Thats why I did it that way. Of course you couldn't know that.

Comment: Ah. OK. That makes sense, and I see your problem now. Still, I think you are really close. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm impressed, thanks a lot for your answer! I can also not use the name of the tag (`div`) but if I remove the selector it still works! Great!

Comment: Upps. I guess I didn't click "run". I didn't work with just removing the `div`.
I had to use the `body` tag as a reference like this: `body :not(.enabled,.sortable)`
see: http://jsfiddle.net/vdun28bj/25/

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why `not:(.enabled,.sortable)` leads to the desired outcome. Can you please tell me?

Comment: I've added a `div` between an `enabled` element and a `sortable` element to add a nested list. The `div` in between will carry more information in my case. But it doesn't work as expected.
Here is the changed jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vdun28bj/30/ .
I changed `sortable` to `component-container` and `enabled` to `component` to better match my own use case.

For me the selector means: "Select all elements below the body tag that have no `enabled`class and no `sortable` class." But that doesn't fit to the actual outcome as "component with container with wrapped empty div" is a component.

Comment: Ok, I probably understand. The examination goes down from the root element and as soon as there is an element that is neither enabled nor sortable it is excluded from the sortables and child elements are not considered anymore. So what I want and what actually works is `body .component-container > :not(.component,.component-container)` which specifies that only direct childs that are not components (former enabled) and not component-containers (former sortables) are canceled.
See: http://jsfiddle.net/vdun28bj/31/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable",
        cancel: ".notsortable, .prueba",
cursor:move,
    });
});
```

```css
.sortable {
    padding-left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="sortable">
<div class="notsortable">Item 1 (disabled)</div>
<div>Item 2</div>
<div class="prueba">Item 3</div>
<div class="notsortable">Item 4 (disabled)</div>
<div class="notsortable">Item 5 (disabled)</div>
<div>Item 6
    <div class="sortable">
        <div class="notsortable">Item 6.1 (disabled)</div>
        <div class="notsortable">Item 6.2 (disabled)</div>
        <div>Item 6.3</div>
        <div>Item 6.4</div>
        <div>Item 6.5</div>
        <div class="sortable">
            <div>Item 6.5.1</div>
            <div>Item 6.5.2</div>
            <div>Item 6.5.3</div>
            <div class="notsortable">Item 6.5.4 (disabled)</div>
            <div class="notsortable">Item 6.5.5 (disabled)</div>
            <div class="sortable">
                <div class="notsortable">Item 6.5.5.1 (disabled)</div>
                <div class="notsortable">Item 6.5.5.2 (disabled)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>Item 7</div>
</div>
```